# Match Function Without Ordered Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The syntax for the Match function in Excel is:

```
=MATCH(Value, Range, Match Type)
```

where the Match Type is 1 for values less than or equal to the specified value, 0 for an exact match, and -1 for greater than or equal to.

My problem is that for the match type to work, the data needs to be ordered in ascending or descending order (for exact matches, this is not the case). But how can I work around this for data that isn't and can't be ordered? Note that it can't be ordered by values because it's ordered by date; the whole point of me looking for the row number is quantify how long it takes something to double or recover, etc. etc.

For example, from cells `A1:A5` there are the following values: c(1,3,5,2,4). I want to find the first instance of a value greater than 2. The formula I use is:`=MATCH(2,A1:A5,-1)`.The return I get is of course #N/A since the data is not ordered by value. The return I want to get is 2, since the 2nd row (3) is greater than the value 2.

Comment: Not understanding the down votes. If I'm overlooking something simple or have formatted the question incorrectly, please let me know and I'll fix it

Comment: I did not downvote, but please update your question with a **specific example** of demo data, the formula you tried and the fail-result.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent updated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C1:C5>2,0),)
```

[image]

*(don't forget that final comma)*

**EDIT#1:**

As Ron Rosenfeld points out:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,C1:C5>2,0)
```

also works

Comment: Why `INDEX`.  Why not just `=MATCH(TRUE,A1:A5>2,0)`  or, in your example `=MATCH(TRUE,C1:C5>2,0)`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good suggestion..................I will update the answer.

Comment: The Match formula without Index only works as an array formula, while the Match/Index formula works as a standard formula, which is faster and usually preferable.